# How to prevent maximized window from resizing when loading a new FXML in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, window, fxml

I've created an `SSCCE` in `JavaFX` to demonstrate the problem. It has two scenes. The dimension of both scenes and the stage is  `600 x 400`. Each scene has one button. When you press it, it takes you to the other scene. It works fine.

The problem is this:

If I change the scene while the program `window/stage` is maximized, the window shrinks in size to `600 x 400` and settles at the top left corner of the computer screen. When I hover the cursor over the 'Maximize/Restore Down' button, it says 'Restore Down'. So the program thinks it's still maximized. But it's not. If I click "Restore Down' the window moves to the center of the computer screen after restoring down.

While the window is maximized, I want it to stay that way when changing scenes. Could anyone show me how it's done? I'm quite new to `JavaFX`.

There's something that may be relevant here. In my `FXML` file you can see that I've put the button in a `GridPane`. The `GridPane` is inside a Group. And the Group is inside a `StackPane`. It's necessary. Because I prefer to use the `GridPane`. And I don't want my buttons, `textfields`, etc to move when the window/stage is resized. Hence I've put the `GridPane` inside a Group. And I want the scene to be centered when the window is maximized. So I've put the Group inside a `StackPane`.

My `SSCCE` has two `FXML` files and three classes. One class has the main method. The other two classes are controllers.

This is the class with the main method:

```
package com;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Launcher extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            StackPane pane = (StackPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/Scene1.fxml"));
            Scene viewScene = new Scene(pane, 600, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(viewScene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The controller class of the first Scene:

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Scene1Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    public void changeScene(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        // Changes the scene
        StackPane pane = FXMLLoader
                .load(getClass().getResource("/com/Scene2.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

The FXML file of the above controller.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.131" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.Scene1Controller">
   <children>
      <Group>
         <children>
            <GridPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="204.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="0.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="370.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="370.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="400.0" fitWidth="600.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets top="28.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#changeScene" text="Go to Scene 2" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="260.0" />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
         </children>
      </Group>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

I've shared just one `FXML` file and its controller class here. It's because the other `FXML` and controller class are pretty much identical to the given `FXML` and controller.

During my searches, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642523/javafx-how-to-keep-the-window-maximizing) question here where the person was advised to consider changing the root instead of the scene. I really don't know how it's done or if it can fix my problem. I need a separate `FXML` and Controller for each change in the screen for my program.

Thanks a lot for your time. Please, let me know if the question needs more clarity. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try answers provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39985414/8555304) question. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39985521/8555304) solves the problem in two different ways. First one changes the root while loading a new scene and second solution suggested initiates a new scene with provided width and height values.

Comment: Thank you. That seems very promising. It works when I load an FXML from the start method and then load another FXML file from the same method after a delay. It works beautifully. The window stays maximized. But I don't know how to use the code in a controller. After getting the root, I have to set it in a scene right? I don't know how to access it. I tried creating a new scene and putting the root in it. But it doesn't work. It doesn't throw any exceptions either. I just doesn't do anything as if there were no instructions on what to do.

Comment: You can define controller of an FXML file in it using fx:controller command Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/why_use_fxml.htm) FXML Getting Started guide. You can also manually do it like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14360940/8555304) answer. But I would suggest you to start JavaFX using getting started guide and moving step by step.

Comment: thanks for the links. I'll go through them. Also, the I've found answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721504/how-to-switch-the-root-from-controllers-without-resizing-the-window-in-javafx